# dryioc - get target type while registration

Tags: c#, dryioc

Is it possible to get type of target (consumer) of the resolved instance while registration?
Basically something like this: [Determine the target type for a dependency during resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67598070/determine-the-target-type-for-a-dependency-during-resolution)
but for dryioc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example from the DryIoc docs: https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/ExamplesContextBasedResolution.md#log4net-logger